# Disable permissions for a certain activity within an app

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech

I am creating a simple app.  What I have currently found is that when I open my app, the following permission have been set in the `.gradle` folder:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

However my app has a second activity called Gvoice.java which then relies on googles speech to text.

What I have found is that if I keep the above permissions in the .gradle folder my main activity window works perfectly with pocketsphinx.  However my Gvoice activity gives me a message `'Can't open microphone'`.

But what I have found is that if I remove the three permissions in the .gradle folder.  My main activity no longer does what I want it to do but my second activity called Gvoice now correctly converts speech to text and does not give me the `'Can't open microphone'` message.

Is there an easy way to fix this issue as I believe it has definitely got to be related to microphone permissions.  Please also note that whenever I return to the main activity the permissions need to be set and when I am in another activity outside of the main activity it needs to disable the permission (or alternatively if there is another way of doing this).

Can different permissions be set for different activities in the manifest file?

Below I have updated what I have got so far please have a look:

```
public class PocketSphinxActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener
{

private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";

/* Keyword we are looking for to activate menu */
private static final String KEYPHRASE = "open voice command";   //adjust this keyphrase here and in string!

private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;

ListView lv;
TextView tv;
EditText a;
Button b;
Button c;

Boolean isDone = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);

    // Prepare the data for UI
    captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
            .setText("Preparing the recognizer");

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
    a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
    c = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Blogin);

    // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
    // so we execute it in async task

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Assets assets = new Assets(PocketSphinxActivity.this);
                File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                setupRecognizer(assetDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
            if (result != null) {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                        .setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
            } else {
                switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
//line added.../////////////////////////
    a.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("open voice command")) {
                //
                //Do your stuff here OR button.performClick()
                //

                //DELAY
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!isDone) {
                            b.performClick();
                            isDone = true;
                        }
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
////////////////////////////////////////
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    recognizer.cancel();
    recognizer.shutdown();
}

/**
 * In partial result we get quick updates about current hypothesis. In
 * keyword spotting mode we can react here, in other modes we need to wait
 * for final result in onResult.
 */
@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis == null)
        return;

    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername)).setText(text);
}

/**
 * This callback is called when we stop the recognizer.
 */
@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("");
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername)).setText("");
    if (hypothesis != null) {
        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    //a.setText((String) tv.getText());
        //tv = TextView.getText().toString();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
}

/**
 * We stop recognizer here to get a final result
 */
@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    if (!recognizer.getSearchName().equals(KWS_SEARCH))
        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
}

private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
    recognizer.stop();

    // If we are not spotting, start listening with timeout (10000 ms or 10 seconds).
    if (searchName.equals(KWS_SEARCH))
        recognizer.startListening(searchName);
    else
        recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);

    String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(caption);
}

private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
    // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
    // of different kind and switch between them

    recognizer = defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))

                    // To disable logging of raw audio comment out this call (takes a lot of space on the device)
            .setRawLogDir(assetsDir)

                    // Threshold to tune for keyphrase to balance between false alarms and misses
            .setKeywordThreshold(1e-45f)

                    // Use context-independent phonetic search, context-dependent is too slow for mobile
            .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)

            .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);

    /** In your application you might not need to add all those searches.
     * They are added here for demonstration. You can leave just one.
     */

    // Create keyword-activation search.
    recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);

}

@Override
public void onError(Exception error) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(error.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void onTimeout() {
    switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
}

//Assign button clicks to go to a new activity:
public void onButtonClick_1(View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bVoice){
        String str_1 = a.getText().toString();

        //Go to the relevant page if any part of the phrase or word entered in the 'EditText' field contains 'command' which is not case sensitive
        if (str_1.toLowerCase().contains("command")) {
            Intent userintent = new Intent(PocketSphinxActivity.this, Gvoice.class);

            startActivity(userintent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IN order to use the microphone you need to have record AUDIO, this is a requirement. You cannot not have that permission for voice recording and if it require that being sent to the cloud, then you also need internet. And depending on which version of android you are running on it will vary as Andoroid M has changed the permission structure. If its prior to android  M you cannot change your permission at runtime at all. Also make sure to clean up your resources.

Comment: Sounds like you are not releasing the microphone resources in main activity. You may want to post the relevant source code.

Comment: I have posted the source code for the main activity, the second activity is just a simple speech to text activity at the moment, By the way I am running on a Nexus 6p (Android M)

Comment: Have you had a look at the source code I provided @ozbek,  I'll really appreciate any method of doing this within a single app please

Comment: I have cleaned up resources etc @JoxTraex.  But this wasn't an issue.  Have you got any possible suggestion on how to implement both methods for the one app?

Comment: Sorry, I saw you removed the source code later and thought you already have resolved the issue... As I mentioned in previous comment, you are not releasing the mic resources. I.e., try to initialize the speech recognizer in `onResume()` and cancel/destroy it in `onPause()`; `onDestroy()` will not be called until your main activity is completely removed from the stack.

Comment: I would recommend exploring all comments, a comment is not an answer per se, but it is a direction of where to start looking and @ozbek has something that may be of value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ozbek. I think I almost understand what you are trying to say but as I have not as much experience in this, something that may make a lot of sense to others more knowledgeable may not be the case for people new like me.  I think I understand the onResume and onPause part. This is done for the Main Activity using pocketsphinx correct?  Do you have an example of part of a code I need to write to initialise and cancel the speech recognizer? I should be able to Google and figure out the rest. Thanks

Comment: I have provided the updated source code @ozbek.  I'll really appreciate if you can have a look and let me know which line to delete and add into `onResume`.

Comment: As @ozbek has correctly said, you are not releasing the audio resource (mic) in `onPause` and consuming again in `onResume`. Consequently, unless `onDestroy` is called, you are holding on to the microphone.

Comment: Yes, you can either use the `noHistory` option in the manifest file or you can use `onPause`.

Comment: Using `noHistory` is not a solution, it just happens to work in most cases. When your app is no longer in the foreground, for reasons like an incoming call is received, you don't want your user experience to be lost, you want it to be **paused**. Correct management of `onPause` and `onResume` is a basic fundamental requirement, that using `noHistory` will temporarily avoid for you.

Comment: I'm not sure why your are saying this is not a solution @brandall.  I was after any method that would work and in this instance this does solve my issue.  What you could say is that it isn't the best answer.  But I have updated my answer now to also now include the `onPause` method which you recommended.  Hopefully this is a better solution you will agree with : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my comment I said:

Using `noHistory` is not a solution, it just happens to work in most cases. When your app is no longer in the foreground, for reasons like an incoming call is received, you don't want your user experience to be lost, you want it to be **paused**. Correct management of onPause and onResume is a basic fundamental requirement, that using `noHistory` will temporarily avoid for you.

Here is an example of how you manage the `recognizer` object when your app is paused and subsequently resumed.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (recognizer == null) {
        // Set up recognizer again
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (recognizer != null) {
        recognizer.cancel();
        recognizer.shutdown();
        recognizer = null;
    }
}
```

Whilst destroying your app every time it is *paused*, will resolve the solution of releasing the microphone and recognizer resource, this is not what you want to do - you want to gracefully manage the lifecycle of your application going into the background and coming to the foreground again, without the resources you are holding on to (such as the mic) causing an issue for other applications.

Comment: I agree, my answer was partly correct but, yes I can fully understand what you mean and hence even when pressing the back button on my app, I can now see the full history of actions rather than destroying what was previously done

Comment: Cool. I added a missing line, where the `recognizer` should have been set to `null` in `onPause()`

Comment: Hey @brandall any chance you could please help me with another question which leads on to the above you helped me with?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177064/enable-push-to-talk-microphone-permission-on-android-app

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out an alternative method is to add the following to my manifest file `android:noHistory="true"`  this seems to clear history of the main activity stack and now the onClickListener is working in the second activity.

The alternative is to place the following at the bottom of my MainActivity file which is the `onPause` method that @brandall suggested:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
finish();
}
```

Comment: The only issue I can currently see with this method is that it will not let me ever go back to the main activity, do people have any other alternatives as I do need to go back to the main activity from time to time using a button press etc?

Comment: This isn't what I meant in my comment. I'll add an answer.